# psql -d {databasename} without specifying user or hostname

Tags: postgresql

I have two Linux systems with Postgresql:

1. Ubuntu 12.04 with Postgresql 9.1
2. Ubuntu 14.04 with Postgresql 9.3

On both, I have created the same users and databases (with the same owners).  They also have the same .pgpass file and more or less the same pg_hba.conf files.  Both pg_hba.conf files contain:

```
local   all             postgres                                peer
local   all             all                                     peer
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5
```

I should also add that PGHOST is specified on neither machine.

However, whereas on (1) I can run the following directly:

```
psql -d myDB
```

on (2) I need to specify the username and hostname:

```
psql -d myDB -U myDBuser -h localhost
```

or I get the following error:

```
psql: FATAL:  role "ubuntu" does not exist
```

Why is this the case, and how can I make (2) like (1) (to save a bit of typing)?

Answer (score 5):

## Why's it happening?

`psql` (and other libpq apps) default to connecting:

- Over unix sockets, if available
- As the current operating system user
- To a database of the same name as the default username

## Just set the client defaults to use tcp/ip

You can [create a `.pgservice` file](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-pgservice.html) that lets you specify a set of connection options, e.g.

```
[mydb]
host=localhost
user=myDBUser
dbname=mydb
```

Then just run

```
psql service=mydb
```

You can also make a shell alias, like

```
alias mypsql='psql service=myservice'
```

or without the service file:

```
alias mypsql='psql "dbname=myDB user=myDBuser host=localhost"
```

which allows you to just run `mypsql` instead.

## Or configure username mapping/password auth for unix sockets

The underlying cause of your original error is probably that you've configured `peer` authentication for `local` connections (or that was the default). So if the username you're connecting as isn't the same as the local unix user, you'll get an error saying:

```
FATAL:  Peer authentication failed for user "myunixusername"
```

which is by the sounds of things, the user `ubuntu`.

If you wish to permit connections over unix sockets so you don't have to specify `-h localhost`, you should use `md5` password authentication for `local` connections in `pg_hba.conf`, or [add a `pg_ident.conf` entry mapping the OS user `ubuntu` to the postgres user `myDBuser` so it's allowed to log in](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/auth-username-maps.html).

So *either* prepend:

```
local   myDB             myDBuser                                md5
```

before other entries in `pg_hba.conf` (to use password auth) *or* prepend:

```
local   all             postgres                                peer map=peermap
```

and in `pg_ident.conf` add:

```
peermap    ubuntu     myDBuser
```

to instead use `peer` auth (so no password, just secure username matching) but allow OS user `ubuntu` to connect as db user `myDBuser`.

`local` connections using unix domain sockets are slightly faster, but there's otherwise no real advantage over TCP/IP.

### Default database

There's no shortcut for setting a default database for a username. So you'll still need to use a pgservice file or shell alias for that.